# Restrict Enum values in SAP Hybris Commerce Backoffice

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

I have an Enum that can be edited in SAP Hybris Commerce Backoffice Administration Cockpit. How can I restrict the values that can be chosen? Is it possible to write a custom `AbstractCockpitEditorRenderer` to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can extend defaultenum editor for removing values from combo. Also you need protection for impex or other scenarios. You can create validator for protection.